# PHP function using & operator

Tags: php

```
<?php
function zz(& $x)
{
    $x=$x+5;
}

$x=10;
zz($x);
echo $x;
```

I used the above code, but I don't know what the `&` symbol means.

Comment: Why did you use the above code, if you don't know what the `&` symbol means?

Answer (score 5):

This refers to [passing a variable by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

To better understand what this means, perhaps try playing around with it a little.  [Run it with the ampersand](http://ideone.com/2ADgB) and [run it without the ampersand](http://ideone.com/nMFmk).  You'll notice that *without* the ampersand, `$x` stays as `10`, because the variable `$x` is passed by value.  This means that just the value `10` is passed to the function; when it is updated, this has no effect on the outer scope.  *With* the ampersand, the variable `$x` is passed in such a way that the variable may be modified by the function.

Answer (score 2):

[it means passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

short: function can change variable which you passed to it

Answer (score 1):

The & means to pass the variable by reference. In this case the x outside the function is increased by five, which wouldn't be increased if & wasn't present.

Comment: What do you mean by "bypass the variable with reference"?

Comment: sorry, I corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` followed by a `$variable` specifies that you are sending the address of a variable so that the value of the variables referencing address gets updated instead of the value.

You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can modify the variable. See [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) for more info!

Comment: Are you sure you meant to put this in a PHP question?

Comment: Well, kinda confused. But the concept was same, anyways, removed the C++ stuff and replaced with PHP. Thanks. :)

Comment: The address doesn't get updated. The address stays the same. The value gets updated.

Comment: @Radu the **value** in that address gets updated!

Comment: @PraveenKumar, you said "the adress gets updated instead of the value"...

Comment: It's still wrong. You have still said that the address gets updated.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I said the **variables referencing the address**, which means the **variables** in this aspect. Do you know English? Or is my English wrong? Please clarify!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say with "variables referencing address" and "instead of the value". And yes, I am English.